# Carregar webView após clicar em permitir no SWIFT 3

Tags: swift, firebase

Tenho um webView que captura o token do aparelho utilizando a biblioteca do firebase e em seguida envia para minha url via get. Até ai td certo, consegui pegar o token, e consigo enviar para a url e em back-end já insiro em banco de dados, td tranquilamente, o problema q estou tendo é q na primeira vez q o aplicativo é aberto após instalado ele solicita minha permissão para receber notificações, porém com isso n consigo enviar o token para a url pois o mesmo ñ é gerado. Existe alguma forma de chamar uma função após eu clicar em permitir?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Caso o usuário permitir o recebimento de notificações, você receberá um callback no seu AppDelegate, você deve implementar o seu código no seguinte método:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data)
{
    // insira seu código aqui
}
```

Caso o usuário não permitir o recebimento de notificações, então método chamado será:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error)
{
    // insira seu código aqui
}
```

Você pode ler mais sobre os métodos na documentação:
[UIApplicationDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate)